# create dummy variable from string variable

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I am trying to create a dummy variable from a column variable from an existing data set. The variable I am interested in is a title in this format:

CHEMICALS - Commission Delegated Directive (EU) 2015/863 of 31 March 2015 amending Annex II to Directive 2011/65/EU of the European Parliament and of the Council as regards the list of restricted substances (Text with EEA relevance)

or

Commission Implementing Directive (EU) 2015/2392...

I want to create a dummy variable indicating that the Title is either implementing or delegated. In other words, when the word "delegated" is in my title variable, this will be labeled 1 and everything else will be labeled 0.

Can anyone help me with this? It is very appreciated. So far, I have used this code:

```
infringements$delegated <- ifelse(infringements$Title=="Delegated", 1, 0)
table(infringements$delegated, infringements$Title)  
summary(infringements$delegated)
```

When I run the code, I get 0 matches, even though I know that there are 41 matches.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal data example?

Comment: You can use `str_detect()` from the package `stringr` instead of `==` because `==` will only check if your string is equal to `"Delegated"` and what you're trying to do is to detect a pattern in your title.

Comment: Use `grepl`, i.e. `as.integer(grepl('Delegated', infringements$Title))`

Comment: great, thank you! I used the grepl suggestion because I have already been working with the grep package, and this worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str_detect()` from the package `stringr`

```
library(stringr)

as.integer(str_detect(infringements$Title,"Delegated"))
```

Answer (score 4):

We can do

```
+(grepl('Delegated', infringements$Title))
```

Comment: What is "+" sign is stands for?

Comment: @AleksandrVoitov  It is a hacky way to coerce the logical to binary.  Better approach is `as.integer(grepl(...`

Answer (score 1):

```
infringements = data.frame(lapply(data.frame(Title=c("CHEMICALS - Commission Delegated Directive (EU) 2015/863 of 31 March 2015 amending Annex II to Directive 2011/65/EU of the European Parliament and of the Council as regards the list of restricted substances (Text with EEA relevance)","No Text","Text3Delegated")), as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
infringements$delegated = lapply(infringements$Title, function(x) ifelse(length(grep("Delegated", x))!=0, 1, 0))
```